# Can't seek video with file size > 10MB in localhost - Django

Tags: python, django

I have an issue about video in Django.

I have 2 videos.

**Video 1**: **smaller than 10MB**, have URL: `http://localhost:8000/media/users/2/videos/9.mp4`

This video can be loaded and seeked normally, **no error**

You can see this video: https://www.youtube.com/embed/u2XXkkpE_Ns

**Video 1**: **larger than 10MB**, have URL: `http://localhost:8000/media/users/2/videos/58.mp4`

This video cannot be loaded and seeked normally. It load partially and I can't even seek it.

Please see this error in video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RoVLUL__JQ

What is this problem? Is this an issue coming by Server?

Comment: They might just be encoded differently.  In more advanced encoders there's a special muxer flag to an index to the file that allows seeks from web streams. For example: https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/advanced/web-optimised.html

Comment: So do you have any solution for me, bro?

Comment: The test server in django may not be optimized to serve such large files. I suspect something like your browser buffering 10 MB, so you can seek without a problem, but sending Range-Requests for larger files. Can you test if you can resume an incomplete download of the file?

Comment: @allo I cant resume an incomplete download of the file, bro